# How do I coordinate timing of animations with rspec and capyabara

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm having trouble getting an rspec test to work without calling sleep:

```
it 'should allow deleting of foo brand attributes', :js => true do                                                                                            
  @foo.brand_attributes << BrandAttribute.new(key: :test, value: :test)                                                                                 
  @foo.save!                                                                                                                                            
  @foo.brand_attributes.length.should eq 1                                                                                                              
  visit('/admin')                                                                                                                                         
  expect(page).to have_content 'Test Foo'                                                                                                               
  click_link 'Edit'    
  # Edit opens a modal edit form with a list of attribute fields                                                                                                                                   
  page.should have_selector('#edit-modal-div', visible: true)                                                                                            
  page.should have_selector('.attribute_fields', visible: true)
  page.should have_selector('.attribute_fields input[type=hidden]') 
  # 1st sleep:
  sleep 0.3                                                                                      
  within(:css, "#edit-modal-div") do   
    # should update hidden input with destroy value                                                                                                                  
    click_link 'Delete'                                                                                                                                   
  end
  # 2nd sleep                                                                                                                                               
  sleep 0.3                                                                                                                                               
  page.should have_selector('.attribute_fields', visible: false)                                                                                          

  within(:css, "#edit-modal-div") do                                                                                                                     
    click_button 'Save'                                                                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                     

  page.find('.alert').should have_content 'successfully updated'                                                                                          
  @foo = Foo.find(@food.id)                                                                                                                          
  @foo.brand_attributes.length.should eq 0
```

My expection is that the "page.should have_selector(" calls should wait until the jquery animations are finished after clicking Edit, but for some reason the Delete button doesn't update the hidden field unless I insert a sleep before the call to click Delete. It seems like something on the page is not quite ready.

wait_until is deprecated so what is the best way to determine that the Delete button is ready to be clicked?

I tried changing my link to just this:

```
<a class="destroy_link" href="#" onclick="x = 4; return false;">Delete</a>
```

When I click 'Delete' it doesn't set x to 4. It looks like the onclick handler isn't initialized by the time capybara triggers a click. Is there something I need to wait for?

Comment: `have_...` matchers can be used in most of situations where `wait_until` was used before. Is there something on a page that appears/disappears at the same moment when Delete button becomes ready?

Comment: The three have... selectors in my example all check for element that appear when the delete button appears. But even a simple onclick attached to the Delete button does not get executed.